# Example for NSAttributedString with NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName

Tags: ios

I'm looking for an example of using NSAttributedString with NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see that the character attribute you list "NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName" is available in iOS. There are a couple that are similar as listed in [NSAttributedString reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688-CH1-SW16)

```
NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
NSStrokeColorAttributeName
```

You could combine these two if necessary to get what you want.